# Is it possible to get multiple random api key from .env?

Tags: reactjs, api

In my .env file there  is something like this:

```
GOOGLE_MAP_API=AIzaSyByfXuuwxOIaWlefhSxqhMweF-0
Another_API_KEY=5893978af2537e042beb233b1
```

I would like to create a .env file in which "Another_API_KEY" is randomly choosen from multiple api keys list.

Something like this:

```
GOOGLE_MAP_API=AIzaSyByfXuuwxOIaWlefhSxqhMweF-0
    var r_text = new Array();
 r_text[0] = "a3219d4e2772db6e34c62144b27f";
 r_text[1] = "5bbe61fe6db548e665a49663eba2";
 r_text[2] = "d74ae61790a9937e3f6d5d3ddc83";

    var nn = Math.floor(3 * Math.random());
    var Another_API_KEY = r_text[nn]
```

But this is'n working. Is this possible to get random keys from the list to React JS Application from .env file?

Comment: In my opinion, the `.env` file is meant to store environment variables. Key-value pairs in plain text format, in `.env` file. You can't use JavaScript as you want.

Comment: You want to set `Another_API_KEY` value inside the .env file from react ? It isn't clear what isn't working from your question :)

Comment: Yes, I would like to set a few Another_API_KEY the .env or for example in app.js file if it's possible.

Comment: @John One of the purpose of the `.env` file is to stock API key, database password ... outside of your code. So updating the `.env` from the `app.js` file (from Node.js ?) is not a good idea, and anyway since you have your keys inside the javascript why not use it directly ? What is the original problem, do you want to store an array in the .env ?

Answer (score 0):

`.env` files store strings so it's not possible to run Javascript inside it.

What you can do, however, is store all keys you want to randomly pick up from in `.env` and, when you use them inside your app, you pick one of them.

`.env`

```
GOOGLE_MAP_API=AIzaSyByfXuuwxOIaWlefhSxqhMweF-0
RANDOM_KEYS="a3219d4e2772db6e34c62144b27f 5bbe61fe6db548e665a49663eba2 d74ae61790a9937e3f6d5d3ddc83"
```

Then on your code:

```js
// Choose random key from all options
const RANDOM_KEYS_ARRAY = process.env.RANDOM_KEYS.split(" ")
const RANDOM_KEY = RANDOM_KEYS_ARRAY[Math.floor(RANDOM_KEYS_ARRAY.length * Math.random())]
```

Here's a sandbox with working code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-random-key-from-env-xuup4r

Comment: I did like you wrote and nothing works:

Comment: @John, just added a working example. Everytime App() is mounted, it will get a random key from RANDOM_KEYS

Comment: Thank you João Pesce. You right , it works in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it.

I the file app.js where the command was to get api key from .env: &appid=${process.env.REACT_API_KEY}

I deleted: process.env.
and inserted

```js
'var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "456afa82537e042beb233b25";
r_text[1] = "s54667e042b33b1fa525";
r_text[2] = "456a82537e042beb233b525";

var nn = Math.floor(3 * Math.random());
var REACT_API_KEY = r_text[nn];'
```

And it works. Thank you